# My pong project is not positioning right in FF

Tags: html, css, firefox

http://warhawkcomputers.com/Birenbaum/Projects/Pong/Pong.html

Hey guys, so I fixed all of my projects except for pong under the fourth quarter tab of the website. It's keypresses and movements work perfectly fine, but for some reason the positioning is off in firefox. Both IE and FF recognizing the elements are associated with the second table, but for some reason firefox continues to think that (0,0) is the upper left corner of the page, not the associated table. Thanks guys.

Comment: That's the first time I've seen the homework tag. Pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `position: relative;` to a containing div for the paddles.

Answer (score 0):

When giving items an absolute positioning, you are automatically assigning that absolute positioning from the next defined container. This container must also have absolute positioning for these child elements to have absolute positioning from the 0,0 position of the parent container.

Here is your code (from your page):

```
<table height="300" width="575" bordercolor="#000" border="1px" style="position:relative;"> 
<tr> 
<td> 
<img src="Images/Paddle1.JPG" style="position:absolute; top:5px; left:3px;" id="Paddle1" /> 
<img src="Images/Paddle2.JPG" style="position:absolute; top:5px; left:555px;" id="Paddle2" /> 
<img src="Images/Ball.JPG" style="position:absolute; top:120px; left:265px;" id="Ball" /> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

In order for absolute positioning for the images to work the way you want them to in FF, you'd have to absolutely position the table containing them.

While I would suggest you use div layers for containing them, it would appear that in your case you could use an easier approach (albeit frowned upon) by creating three columns in your table and use left alignment on the paddle1's td and right alignment on the paddle2's td... Again, but I'd suggest you write it to use div layers to control layout as that's what's considered "proper" nowadays.

[Here's](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/position) a handy reference to view on positioning. Basically it's letting you know that the position property is pretty buggy in most browsers. I'm sure it works in IE because, well, there are a lot of odd coding samples that work in IE... It's strange, but always best to do it proper. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't relatively position a table cell, which is why absolute positioning does not work in a table ;)

I would suggest you put a container div inside that main table cell `width: 575px height: 300px;` or to match the inner width height of that cell and relatively position it instead